# Imagem com link não esta abrindo a pagina

Tags: html, css

Na minha aplicação eu criei os acessos para redes sociais da empresa da qual trabalho.
Porém quando clico na imagem com link, não abre nada.

Segue código:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target= "_blank" style="display:table;padding:15px;background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;
                               background-repeat: no-repeat;margin-top: -80px;margin-left: 91%; position: absolute; "><a/>

                    <a href="https://br.linkedin.com/" target= "_blank" style="display:table;padding:15px; margin-top: 50%; background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Linkedin.svg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;
                                 background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; margin-top: -80px; margin-left: 95%; "><a/>
```

Comment: Olá A´lexandre Lima, não seria assim?     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target= "_blank"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg" width="50" height="50"><a/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você esta utilizando elementos com background, eles não pegam o tamanho da imagem, você precisa setar width e height para os elementos, no exemplo a baixo coloquei só os tamanhos e tirei as margins para mostrar na tela.
Fiz um teste em uma pagina aqui e o link abril, só no console do StackOverflow não esta executando.

```html
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target= "_blank" style="display:table;padding:15px;background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Facebook_icon_2013.svg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;background-repeat: no-repeat;margin-top:0;margin-left: 0; position: absolute;width:50px;height:50px;"><a/>

<a href="https://br.linkedin.com/" target= "_blank" style="display:table;padding:15px; margin-top: 50%; background:url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c9/Linkedin.svg') center;background-size: 30px 30px;background-repeat: no-repeat; position: absolute; margin-top:50px;margin-left:0;width: 50px;height:50px;"><a/>
```

Comment: obs.: como o elemento esta absoluto, é bom jogar um z-index, porque um elemento pode acabar ficando em cima do seu link, nesse caso você não ira conseguir clicar.

Answer (score 0):

Lembrando que a tag 'a' se fecha assim '' e não '', copiei o seu html e só alterei isso e está funcionando normalmente.